# Check Selected Fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form with musicial instruments:

```
class InstrumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    instruments = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Instrument.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Instrument
        fields = ('instruments', )
```

That takes all instruments from model. I need to somehow check selected instruments and save them to Profile Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    instrument = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument, related_name='instruments')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I also have a dummy html page with form, it works:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

But I need to check all instruments that user has selected and save them to the user profile model, how can I do this?

Comment: Just curious, why not create a form for `Profile` model instead of a form for `Instrument` model?

Comment: I want a seperate page where user will select musicial instruments, that he plays